# Generate string of numbers python

Tags: python, numbers

Hello I want to create a list of strings where each string is a number.

Fox example given the number 4 I would like to create a function that returns a list with elements '0','1','2','3','4'. In C/C++ this can be done by using the Ascii code of 0 and then increase them. I am new to python and I don’t know how to do it. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: You seem to be looking for a function called `range()`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do this with `str` and `range` like this

```
map(str, range(number + 1))
```

When `number = 4`,

```
print(map(str, range(4 + 1)))
# ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Answer (score 22):

`map` being frowned upon by many python developers, here is the comprehension list equivalent:

```
 [str(x) for x in range(my_value + 1)]
```